# Add different types of childs to treeview

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I'd like to visualize a collection of `Test` class (POCO from model assembly) in a `TreeView`. Each `Test` instance has got a collection of `Readers` and `Groups`:

Test class pseudo code

```
public class Test 
{
    // properties
   public  ObservableCollection<Reader> Readers { get; set; }
   public  ObservableCollection<Group> Groups { get; set; }
}
```

**What I want**

My goal is to visualize the tests in a `TreeView` like that:

```
Test 1  
   |- Reader 1  
   |- Reader 2  
   |- Group 1   
   |- Group 2

Test 2  
   |- Reader 1  
   |- Group 4   
   |- Group 5
```

**What I got so far**

I can show tests and readers by using a `HierarchicalDataTemplate`

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:Test}" ItemsSource="{Binding Readers}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Basically I want to tell the `TreeView`, "Hey there is another child item source with another template in my test class, use it!".

I tried using a `CompositeCollection` of readers and groups, but got stuck because I don't want to change the Test class (it is generated code).

Comment: Do `Reader` and `Group` share any base? If so, you can expose a Collection of the base type, then just handle it differently in your XAML with a different DataTemplates for each of your concrete types (`Reader` and `Group`)

Comment: [Basically I want to tell the TreeView, "Hey there is another child item source with another template in my test class, use it!"]. that is why they call it MVVM and create view models to provide views with data in convenient form (e.g. CompositeCollection ).

Comment: @ASh: You propose to transform the test class into something more convenient for the view, like a TestViewModel with a compositeCollection of readers and groups. Correct?

Comment: @nabulke, not exactly. I would leave Test (model) class as is, but add TestViewModel for it, and make sure TestViewModel has collection property with both Readers and Groups which can be used as ItemsSource

Comment: @nabulke, or maybe another way: define CompositeCollection in xaml and use two databound CollectionContainers for Readers and Groups

Comment: @ASh: ok, I understand. I was hoping to find a XAML-only solution...probably by some fancy usage of HierarchicalDataTemplates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `Converter` and use it in your `HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource`.

*Converter :*

```
public class ReadersGroupsCombineConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        ObservableCollection<Reader> readers = (value as Test).Readers;
        ObservableCollection<Group> groups = (value as Test).Groups;

        ObservableCollection<object> readersGroups = new ObservableCollection<object>();
        foreach (Reader reader in readers)
            readersGroups.Add(reader);

        foreach (Group group in groups)
            readersGroups.Add(group);

        return readersGroups;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

XAML :

```
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="HDTReaderGroups" ItemsSource="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource ReaderGroupsCombineCnvKey}}">
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I've done in the past, and recommend you to do, is to create a wrapper object for each type you want to represent in the treeview. You can initialize that structure in the viewmodel. When you have all your objects set up, you can do this:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" DataType="{x:Type Model:TestNode}">
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

And now the templates for the children:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" DataType="{x:Type Model:ReaderNode}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>

<HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" DataType="{x:Type Model:GroupNode}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

This way you will have a template for each type of object you are modeling.

As I've said before, I recommend you to do this, because a binding to an object that doesn't implement INotifyPropertyChanged leaks memory, and usually POCOs and DTOs don't implement it. You can see more here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/938416